# Shift-Enter (small) linebreak in WPF textbox c#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a `TextBox` in a `WPF` program.

I want to add specific lines from a text file to the `TextBox`. Between them i want to add a `linebreak`.

However if i add something like

```
myTextBox.Text += "\n";
```

or

```
myTextBox.Text += Environment.NewLine;
```

I get two linebreaks.

If i don't add a linebreak, i get no linebreaks at all and the whole text is in one line.

This is the code i'm using:

```
bool stopReading = false;
while (!stopReading)
{
    string nextLine = reader.ReadLine();
    if (nextLine == "#lineEnd")
    {
        stopReadingZutaten = true;
    }
    else
    {
        myTextBox.Text += nextLine;
        myTextBox.Text += Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

I tried it with `"\n"`, `"\r"`, `"\r\n"` and `Environment.NewLine` , but nothing seems to help.

what i currently get looks like this:

```
line1

line2

line3
```

what i would need is this:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Comment: I think you have another line break already in the `nextLine`. Can you show what's inside the `nextLine` variable?

Comment: @SalahAkbari well if i remove that line "myTextBox.Text += Environment.NewLine" then it writes everything in the same line, so if there would be a line break then this wouldn't happen, or?

Comment: `myTextBox.Text = "line1\nline2\nline3";` works just fine for me and so does `myTextBox.Text = string.Format("line1{0}line2{0}line3", Environment.NewLine);`. There is something else going on in your code or data.

Comment: hmmm then i have to look through it again, didn't found something yet.

Comment: is it somehow possible to check if a line contains a linebreak?

Comment: You could have a carriage return or carriage return and line feed.   bool hasGotCarriageReturnOrLineFeed = str.IndexOfAny(new char[] {'\r', ''\n') != -1

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the TextBox?